# How to use the Paging Library with a RecyclerView GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components

Let's say I have a 2-column RecyclerView that looks something like this:

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

9 10

and so on, infinitely.

Now, whenever the user scrolls and a new PagedList is sent to be displayed, the case should be that the first item on the PagedList be odd. However, I find that this is not the case. When I scroll down, my RecyclerView looks like this:

8 9

10 11

12 13

14 15

16 17

Given that I've only followed the docs and samples (which use LinearLayoutManager), I might be missing something here that let's me set the behaviour I want when using a grid.

Comment: i think the id's start from 0 in a list not 1

Comment: But those are not IDs, just RecyclerView items that display a number.

Comment: i see, well you need to paste the code in your Question to see what's happening

Comment: for displaying 2 column of views in recyclerview just use GridLayoutManager instead of LinearLayoutManager

Comment: Already using a GridLayoutManager hence the 2-column RecyclerView.